# WebView2 lose focus at arrow keys press inside ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.5, webview2

I have an issue with `WebView2` for **WPF**. Inside a `ScrollViewer`, `WebView2` **lose focus at arrow keys press**. Removing the `ScrollViewer`, the `WebView2` focus works correctly, why? There is a way to fix this?

In `WebView2` is rendered an html editor but this is not the cause of the problem.

Example of xaml

```
<ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox />
            <TextBox />
            <TextBox />
            <TextBox />
            <wpf:WebView2 x:Name="wb" Height="200" />
            <TextBox />
            <TextBox />
            <TextBox />
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Specs:

- .net 4.5
- Microsoft Edge WebView2 Runtime 100.0.1185.44

I have created a test project [here](https://github.com/renzodelpiano/TestWebView2)

Comment: I think `ScrollViewer` steals the focus, when you use the arrow keys. It probably has to - to work.

Answer (score 1):

Looking into it, it looks like that's because it's how `ScrollViewer` works - arrow keys are scroll events.

A workaround would be to create a handler for the `PreviewKeyDown` event. If you were to tweak the markup for your `ScrollViewer` to something like the following:

```
<ScrollViewer  x:Name="scroller"  PreviewKeyDown="scroller_PreviewKeyDown">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox />
        <TextBox />
        <TextBox />
        <TextBox />
        <wpf:WebView2 x:Name="wb" Height="200" />
        <TextBox />
        <TextBox />
        <TextBox />
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

You could then do this in the code behind:

```
private void scroller_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
     {
         if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Up || e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Down || e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Left || e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Right)
         {
             e.Handled = true;
         }
     }
```

It just means that you won't be able to scroll using the arrows.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. in this way `e.Handled = true` does not allow the change of position of the cursor inside the text boxes with arrow keys

Comment: @renzo: Make up your mind. Do you want to scroll or do you want to change line in textbox, when pressing an arrow key? It can't do both at the same time.

Comment: @renzo - that's what I said in the last sentence; I'm not sure what alternatives there are for `ScrollViewer` for your particular scenario - but there might be an alternative that doesn't steal the focus.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by inheriting from scroll viewer and overriding OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)

Something like this:

```
   public class CustomScrollViewer:ScrollViewer
    {
        protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if(!(e.OriginalSource is WebView2))
            {
                base.OnKeyDown(e);
            }
        }
```